# Is there a way for two Threads to not get the same item from a shared collection?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program that has 3 threads. One thread is dedicated to adding items to a shared collection and the remaining two threads are for removing an item from the collection and processing it.

I created a Runnable for adding. It looks like this:

```
public class Adder implements Runnable {

    private static final Integer MAX_NO = 1000; // I wanted this to be Integer.MAX_VALUE
    private final List<Integer> shared;
    private final AtomicBoolean isAddingDone;

    public Adder(final List<Integer> shared, final AtomicBoolean isAddingDone) {
        this.shared= shared;
        this.isAddingDone = isAddingDone;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NO; i++) {
            shared.add(i);
        }
        isAddingDone.set(true);
    }

}
```

I created another Runnable that removes an item from the shared collection.

```
public class Remover implements Runnable {

    private final int id;
    private boolean stopRequested = false;
    private final List<Integer> shared;
    private final AtomicBoolean isAddingDone;

    public Remover(final int id, final List<Integer> shared, final AtomicBoolean isAddingDone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.shared = shared;
        this.isAddingDone = isAddingDone;
    }

    public synchronized void requestStop() {
        this.stopRequested = true;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isStopRequested() {
        return this.stopRequested;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting Remover" + id + "...");
        while (!isStopRequested()) {
            if (shared.isEmpty() && isAddingDone.get()) {
                this.requestStop();
            } else {
                final Integer value = shared.get(0);
                System.out.println("Remover" + this.id + " retrieved " + value + ". Removing...");
                shared.remove(value);
                // processing of value here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Integer> shared = new Vector<>();
    final AtomicBoolean isAddingDone = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    final Runnable tAdder = new Adder(shared, isAddingDone);
    final Runnable tRemover0 = new Remover(0, shared, isAddingDone);
    final Runnable tRemover1 = new Remover(1, shared, isAddingDone);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(tAdder, "Thread-Adder");
    t1.start();

    Thread r0 = new Thread(tRemover0, "Thread-Remover0");
    r0.start();

    Thread r1 = new Thread(tRemover1, "Thread-Remover1");
    r1.start();
}
```

I got no errors when running the program but I noticed that at some point both threads are retrieving the same item.

```
Starting Remover0...
Starting Remover1...
Remover1 retrieved 0. Removing...
Remover0 retrieved 0. Removing...
Remover1 retrieved 1. Removing...
Remover0 retrieved 1. Removing...
Remover1 retrieved 2. Removing...
Remover1 retrieved 3. Removing...
```

Is there a way where the two removers are not processing the same item? I tried using an iterator but when running, I got a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: `shared.isEmpty()`, `shared.get(0)` and `shared.remove(value)` don't happen atomically, so there is no guarantee that the list hasn't changed in between.

Comment: Don't use Vector. It's as good as deprecated. There is no reason to choose it nowadays, the implementation is flawed. Use a queue, something like ArrayBlockingQueue

Comment: Thanks for the insight @AndyTurner! How can I guarantee that the item a thread retrieved is not the same item that another thread has already retrieved? Sorry, I'm still studying threading so I have no idea about this.

Comment: I will try this @Michael. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`shared.isEmpty()`, `shared.get(0)` and `shared.remove(value)` don't happen atomically, so there is no guarantee that the list hasn't changed in between.

If you want to communicate between threads, use a `BlockingQueue`, and use `poll()` to remove an item from it if one is available. This allows you to combine the `isEmpty()`, `get` and `remove` into a single atomic action.

```
// From the while loop inside Remover:
            Integer value = shared.poll();
            if (value == null /* indicates the queue was empty when you looked. */
                    && isAddingDone.get()) {
                this.requestStop();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Remover" + this.id + " retrieved " + value + ". Removing...");
                // No need to remove, you already did.
                // processing of value here
            }
```